# Расширение Chrome — как добавить пункт в контекстное меню?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Нужно добавить сюда ссылку на дополнительную страницу UI

Чтобы она была доступна таким же образом как "Параметры" расширения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот [здесь](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus) почитай доку

Код в `background.js` *примерно/уменя* следующий

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(()=>{

    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: 'click1',
        title: 'click1_name',
        contexts: ['browser_action']
    });

    chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(({menuItemId})=>{
        if(menuItemId === 'click1')return chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://www.google.com/'});
    });

});
```